# Why is the Task's Result property unavailable for non-generic Task (C# 4.0+)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am trying to get grasp of .NET 4.0+ Task Parallel Library concepts...

In the following C# 4.0 code snippet:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("I am the task");
   return "res1";
});
```

why compiler doesn't (and run-time either) produce any error if the return cannot be used unless generic Task used instead:

```
Task<string> t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("I am the task");
   return "res1";
});
```

Or it (returned object) can be used?

Do I understand correctly that `<string>` in `Task<string>` is needed only for detecting or assuring the type of return (ed object)  or of `t.Result`?
Or there are any other hidden from me necessities except this?

Why this type cannot cannot be determined from the type of returned object?
I.e. why is the Result property of a task unavailable for non-generic tasks?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The non-generic `Task` does not have a `Result` property because it represents a process that does *not* produce a result.

Your code creates a `Task<string>` in both cases, but in the first case you cast it to a `Task` (`Task<string>` derives from `Task`, so that's legal) and so you lose the ability to refer to the result.

You can see this directly with:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("I am the task");
   return "res1";
});

var genericTask = t as Task<string>; // genericTask will be non-null
var result = genericTask.Result;     // and you can access the result
```

Comment: Yes, I saw it but I couldn't grasp why non-generic task cannot have `Result` property

Comment: @Fulproof It's conceptual thing. `Task` is more or less conceptually equivalent to `void` return type in async/Task world, whereas `Task<T>` is equivalent to `T` return type. Now, given a method `void Foo()` you wouldn't try to do `var result = Foo();`, would you? :)

Comment: Why, then, return-ing from non-generic Task "activity" isn't fetermined by compiler as an error or even warning?

Comment: @Fulproof There's a difference between a concept and the execution. If `void` was a *regular* type, then there would be no need for `Task`. But you can't do `Task<void>`, so there's `Task` and the [class hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) allows to return anything per Jon's answer.

Comment: @Fulproof: Because *you are not returning from a non-generic `Task`*. You are returning from a generic `Task<string>`, and then casting that into a non-generic task.

Comment: @Fulproof: `Task.StartNew` has [many overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321421.aspx), and the one you are using returns a `Task<T>`, not a plain `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

`Task<T>` inherits from `Task`. In both cases you're actually creating a `Task<T>`, but in the first case you're implicitly casting it to `Task`, which doesn't have the `Result` property.